# How to add sticky bits via puppet?

Tags: permissions, puppet

I would like to make sure the files that get added to a certain directory inherits the parent directory's permission and that permission never changes. I guess it's called sticky bit but cannot find a way to do this via puppet. Any info would be much appreciate it. I just need something beside exec to do this and I would be adding this to my init.pp. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, you can do this with the `mode` parameter on a `file` resource by setting the [octal permissions](https://serverfault.com/a/344545/230046) correctly:

e.g.

```
file { "foo":
  path => '/home/user/foo'
  type => 'directory'
  mode => '1750'
}
```

or similar. Syntax not guaranteed to be correct!

If you wanted to do this on files in a directory, you could tie this in to some of the good recipes from the [Puppet Cookbook](https://www.puppetcookbook.com/posts/creating-a-directory-tree.html), perhaps by managing the directory and any files you want and then using a [resource collector](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6/lang_collectors.html) to capture the unlisted files and set permissions?

Comment: Thank you, I already have the file permission stuff straighten out. Was trying to find a way to use the sticky bit on a directory